# Encoding an opencv image into Base64 doesn't produce a valid image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, flask, base64

I am trying to send a picture from my Pi camera to a flask web server. When I encode the image Base64 it doesn't seem to produce a valid image.

I can take the picture and process it through `opencv`. The Base64 encoded image is passed to the web page, but the string sent is not a valid image. To prove this I have saved the image and processed it with an online Base64 converter. Pasting this string into the web page shows the image.

```
def Take_Picture(camera):
    stream = io.BytesIO()                                           # saving the picture to an in-program stream 
    camera.resolution = (160,120)                                   # set resolution
    camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg', use_video_port=True)      # capture into stream
    mydata = np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)       # convert image into numpy array
    img = cv2.imdecode(mydata, -1)                                  # to opencv image
    data = base64.b64encode(img).decode('utf-8')
    print(data)
    cv2.imwrite("test.jpg",img)
    return data
```

HTML

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,{{img}}"  alt="Camera View" width="640" height="480">
```

I get a result of

> b'AAIAAAIAAAIAAAIAAAIAAAIAAAIAAAIAAAIAAAIAAAIAAAMAAAIAAAIAAA...

from data above. 
But I get

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUG...

from `test.jpg` from an online Base64 conversion. Putting this string in the web page displays the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to convert you image back from a numpy array to an image which can then encoded correctly to Base64! 
What you now do is you encode a numpy array to base64 string which surely can't give the same result the online base64 tool gives!

What you need to do, pass your numpy array to `cv2.imencode` which returns a buffer image object and then you can convert it to base64

```
retval, buffer_img= cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
data = base64.b64encode(buffer_img)
```

**OR** 
you can skip the `img = cv2.imdecode(mydata, -1)` and pass `mydata` directly to `base64.b64encode(mydata)` while the image is already stored the memory!

There is no openCV image, the openCV image is a ndArray. When you execute `print(type(img))` you will get `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Thanks, being a newbie, I spent a day on this, just skiped the image conversion & it works.

Comment: No worrie @NeilsS , I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

The following solved it for me:

```
import cv2
import base64

# img is a numpy array / opencv image
_, encoded_img = cv2.imencode('.png', img)  # Works for '.jpg' as well
base64_img = base64.b64encode(encoded_img).decode("utf-8")
```